# How to use array parameter in c# using CLI function?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I want to use array in C# using CLI function.

**CLI Source**

```
public value struct Test
{
    int         nIndex;
    TArrTest    Arr;    // TArrTest : Array struct
}

void Api::Set_Test(array<Test^>^% _Test2)
```

**C# Source**

```
Test[] Test3 = new Test[5];
test3[0].nIndex = 0;
...
...
Api.Set_Test(ref Test3) // Error message
```

Error Message:
The parameter is not convert ref Test[] to ref system.Value[].

How can I call Set_Test in C#?

Comment: Knowing when to use the ^ hat is super-duper important in C++/CLI.  Only use it for reference types (ref class or ref struct).  The % is not correct either, the C++/CLI function doesn't create the array.  Delete both.

Answer (score 1):

Your C++/CLI declaration:

```
void Api::Set_Test(array<Test^>^% _Test2)
```

is incorrect. The array is not an array of `Test` references, since `Test` is a value type. It should be

```
void Api::Set_Test(array<Test>^% _Test2)
                             ^------ remove the reference caret inside the angle brackets
```